# Get Inner Text Value for Second Child

Tags: javascript

I have the following code within a portal product I'm using

```html
<label class ="control-label" for="Classification">
    <span>Classification</span>
    <span> (Required)</span>
```

I need to somehow get the text content of the second child (i.e. the  (Required) in this case.
I can select the parent element without an issue 
var req = $('label[for="Classification"') but can't work out how to select the required child and get it's content as I only need certain code to run if the second child is empty ()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with the `eq` method which is zero-based:

```js
var $secondSpan = $('label[for="Classification"] > span').eq(1);
$secondSpan.css('background-color','green')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class ="control-label" for="Classification">
    <span>Classification</span>
    <span> (Required)</span>
</label>
```

Or with the `:eq` selector if you prefer

```js
var $secondSpan = $('label[for="Classification"] > span:eq(1)');
$secondSpan.css('background-color','green')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class ="control-label" for="Classification">
    <span>Classification</span>
    <span> (Required)</span>
</label>
```

It's worth noting there is an `:empty` selector too:

```js
var $secondSpan = $('label[for="Classification"] > span:eq(1)');
var isEmpty = $secondSpan.is(":empty");
console.log(isEmpty)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class ="control-label" for="Classification">
    <span>Classification</span>
    <span> (Required)</span>
</label>
```

Comment: that works exactly how I need it to! Thanks! How would I go about replacing the content of that child?

Comment: @Alex `.text()` or `.html()` in place of `.css()` in my first 2 examples.

Comment: Thanks very much. Exactly what I needed